# What is the state of the art on the Weber problem?

Tags: optimization, facility-location

I'm trying to get up to speed on the Weber problem. I'm very much not an expert, unfortunately. I would really appreciate recent literature recommendations / surveys / potted histories, however incomplete. And more specifically:

- Is there a solution for rectilinear space?
- Are there multi-dimensional, rather than planar, solutions?

Answer (score 4):

The [Fermat-Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_problem) problem can be formulated as a conic quadratic problem (aka. SOCP). These problems can be solved in polynomial complexity using an interior-point method.
See the [Mosek modelling cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html) for information about conic optimization.

You can use [Mosek](https://mosek.com) to solve those problems.